# SQL Server injection for procedure with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-injection

I used a dynamic SQL in my SQL Server procedure, I replaced all the single quotes with two single quotes before passing the parameters into my procedure. Is that prevent a SQL injection?

My procedure as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CM_LST_XML]  
    (@pTable VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pColumns VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pFilterAndEQ VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pFilterAndLK VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pFilterOrEQ VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pFilterOrLK VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pFilterAdditional VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pSortField VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pDirection VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pAdditionalSort VARCHAR(MAX),
     @pFromRowno INT,
     @pToRowNo INT,
     @pDeleted INT,
     @pDataType INT,
     @pCompany VARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS
     DECLARE @v_sort VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_where VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_whereAndEQ VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_WhereAndLK VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_whereOrEQ VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_WhereOrLK VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_deleted VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_Company VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_DataType VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
     DECLARE @v_sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''; 
     DECLARE @vIndex int;

     BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @idoc INT;
        DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(MAX) ='';
        DECLARE @Field VARCHAR(MAX) ='';
        DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(MAX) =''; 

        -- Add Filter Condition -- AND + EQUAL
        IF LEN(@pFilterAndEQ) > 35   
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @pFilterAndEQ; 

            DECLARE CurName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/data/row',1)  WITH (Type varchar(max),  Field varchar(max),  Value varchar(max))

 OPEN CurName
 FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @v_whereAndEQ = @v_whereAndEQ + ' AND UPPER(' + @Field +  ') = UPPER(''' + @Value +  ''')'; 
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
    END
 CLOSE CurName
 DEALLOCATE CurName
 END

 -- Add Filter Condition -- AND + LIKE
  if LEN(@pFilterAndLK) >35  
  BEGIN
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @pFilterAndLK; 
 DECLARE CurName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
 FOR SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/data/row',1)  WITH (Type varchar(max),  Field varchar(max),  Value varchar(max))

 OPEN CurName
 FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @v_whereAndLK = @v_whereAndLK + ' AND UPPER(' + @Field +  ') LIKE UPPER(''%' + @Value +  '%'')'; 
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
    END
 CLOSE CurName
 DEALLOCATE CurName
 END


 -- Add Filter Condition -- OR + EQUAL
  if LEN(@pFilterOrEQ) >35  
  BEGIN
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @pFilterOrEQ; 
 DECLARE CurName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
 FOR SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/data/row',1)  WITH (Type varchar(max),  Field varchar(max),  Value varchar(max))

 set @vIndex =1;
 OPEN CurName
 FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN  
        if @vIndex = 1  
          set @v_WhereOrEQ = @v_WhereOrEQ + ' AND (UPPER(' + @Field + ') = UPPER(''' + @Value + ''')';
        else
          set @v_WhereOrEQ = @v_WhereOrEQ + ' OR UPPER(' + @Field + ') = UPPER(''' + @Value + ''')';

        set @vIndex = @vIndex + 1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
    END
 CLOSE CurName
 DEALLOCATE CurName

 if LEN(@v_whereOrEQ) > 0  
    set @v_whereOrEQ = @v_whereOrEQ + ') ';
 END   

 -- Add Filter Condition -- OR + LIKE
  if LEN(@pFilterOrLK) >35  
  BEGIN
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @pFilterOrLK; 
 DECLARE CurName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
 FOR SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/data/row',1)  WITH (Type varchar(max),  Field varchar(max),  Value varchar(max))

set @vIndex =1;
 OPEN CurName
 FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        if @vIndex = 1  
          set @v_WhereOrLK = @v_WhereOrLK + ' AND (UPPER(' + @Field + ') LIKE UPPER(''%' + @Value + '%'')';
        else
          set @v_WhereOrLK = @v_WhereOrLK + ' OR UPPER(' + @Field + ') LIKE UPPER(''%' + @Value + '%'')';

        set @vIndex = @vIndex + 1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurName INTO @Type, @Field, @Value
    END
 CLOSE CurName
 DEALLOCATE CurName

if LEN(@v_WhereOrLK) > 0  
    set @v_WhereOrLK = @v_WhereOrLK + ') ';
END


 IF @pDeleted = 0  
    set @v_deleted = @v_deleted + ' AND REC_TYPE <> ''5'' ';


    set @v_DataType = @v_DataType + ' AND DATA_TYPE = ''' + + ''' ';

  IF @pCompany = '0'  
    set @v_Company =  ' AND Created_Comp = ''' +  @pCompany + ''' ';

 set @v_where =  @v_whereAndEQ + ' ' + @v_WhereAndLK + ' ' + @v_whereOrEQ + ' ' + @v_WhereOrLK + ' ';


 if @pDirection = '1'
     set @v_sort = ' desc ';
     else
     set @v_sort = ' asc ';


 SET @v_sql = 'SELECT * FROM (select row_number() OVER (order by ' + @pSortField + ' ' + @v_sort + ' ' + Convert(varchar(max),@pAdditionalSort)  + ') AS DefaultRowIndex, COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalFiltered, TC.TotalRecord, A.' + @pColumns + ' from ' + @pTable + ' A CROSS APPLY (SELECT  count(*) as TotalRecord FROM ' + @pTable + ' where 1 = 1 ' + @v_deleted + ' ' + @v_Company + ') TC WHERE 1 = 1 ' + @v_deleted + ' ' + @v_Company + ' ' + @v_where + @pFilterAdditional + ') TB WHERE TB.DefaultRowIndex >= ' + Convert(varchar(max),@pFromRowno) + ' and TB.DefaultRowIndex <= ' + Convert(varchar(max),@pToRowNo);

    EXEC(@v_sql);


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH;
```

I used XML string for parameters @pFilterAndEQ, @pFilterAndLK, @pFilterOrEQ and @pFilterOrEQ to handle dynamic table's column. The parameters as below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><data><row Type="String" Field="Email" Value="test@test.com" /></data>
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s, Noted with Thanks

Comment: I tried reading your stored procedure's code but it made me want to hide under the bed and pray the boogie man for mercy. I think instead of asking about how to make this procedure safe from SQL injection (which is not going to be such an easy task as just escaping `'` chars, I promise you that) you should ask how to write the sql statement(s) that will produce whatever it is this procedure is supposed to produce. Seeing all these cursors and dynamic SQL leave me with no doubt  - this is, by definition, an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).